# How to enable theme on WordPress on Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile, wp-cli

I am using docker to run a develop environment for several wordpress themes / plugins.  However, I can't figure out how to enable my themes automatically on container creation. Normally I would just use wp-cli for this.  I have created a custom image that extends the official wordpress image, but I can't figure out how to make the wp-cli commands run after the /var/www/html folder get's setup (I think this is created by the wordpress image entrypoint script).  If I put the commands in a "RUN" command in the dockerfile, the commands just fail since the /var/www/html directory is empty.  However, if I connect to the container once it is setup, the directory is populated, and wp-cli works just fine. How can I run a command after the entrypoint.sh from the parent image is run?

Here is the content of my dockerfile (which does not work):

```
FROM wordpress
MAINTAINER Me!
COPY docker-install/wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/wp
RUN /usr/local/bin/wp core install --title="Test WP Site" --admin_user=admin --admin_password=something --admin_email=my@cool.email  --url=localhost:8080 --allow-root
RUN /usr/local/bin/wp theme activate mytheme --allow-root
```

Comment: You'll need to use a custom entrypoint script. `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are runtime instructions so anything you put in the Dockerfile (build-time) will run first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: You can't. The `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` is are used at Docker container runtime, not build time. In this case, the Wordpress environment is actually started at container runtime so you can't interact with it during a build.

The long answer: You might be able to help accomplish your goals by using Docker Compose to create two services, one for Wordpress and another for the Wordpress CLI variant (see the `cli` tags at https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) with a `volumes_from` the first one. Then, you could use `docker-compose run cli-service wp-cli command` to run your commands.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `prepare.sh` file that contains commands I want to run before Apache starts, and then added this to the Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./prepare.sh /prepare.sh
RUN chmod +x /prepare.sh
CMD /prepare.sh && apache2-foreground
```

Comment: Have you tried this script?

If You view the original docker-entrypoint.sh https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/0a5405cca8daf0338cf32dc7be26f4df5405cfb6/php5.6/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L26 checks if de CMD starts with apache2 but this overrided script doesn't

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I have tried it and it works. What is the purpose of that line?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a script that install themes after docker-entrypoint. The name has to start with apache2 (docker-entrypoint checks name of CMD param https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/0a5405cca8daf0338cf32dc7be26f4df5405cfb6/php5.6/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L26), for example apache2-setup-wordpress.sh.

Dockerfile would be like this

```
FROM wordpress:4.7.3

COPY apache2-setup-wordpress.sh /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/apache2-setup-wordpress.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-setup-wordpress.sh", "apache2-foreground"]
```